# how to get value from sql in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-mysql

I am stuck @ one of the problem in express node js. I am getting error "url not defined"

```
 app.get("/id", function(req, res) {
 var id = req.param("id");
  connection.query('SELECT `url` FROM dynamic_url where id ='+req.param("id"), function          (error, rows, fields) {
 //how do i get the values of url here
res.send("value of url is " + url);
});
});
```

Comment: add info, which sql module you are using

Comment: I can't test it right now but I would say you should use: rows[0].url (if it won't work just do console.log(rows) and you will see response structure).

Comment: i had tried using it.it gives error 0 is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because the `url` variable isn't defined anywhere.

The results of the MySQL request are available in the second parameter of the callback:

```
app.get("/id", function(req, res, next) {
  var id = req.param("id");
  connection.query('SELECT `url` FROM dynamic_url where id ='+req.param("id"), function (error, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    var url;
    if (rows.length === 0) {
      url = 'URL not available in database'
    } else {
      url =  rows[0].url;
    }
    res.send("value of url is " + url);
  });
});
```

Check [mysql's documentation](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#introduction) for a sample request.

Comment: Indeed, forgot the last parameter. Updated my answer to include it.

Comment: This is not an error. The `rows` array contains objects. Please use `JSON.stringify()` or `console.log()` in order to know what they contain.

Comment: Okay, is there any method to get string data or any conversion which convert json to string

Comment: As stated in my previous comment, `JSON.stringify(rows)` will transform an object into a string.